# In a dask distributed setup the worker sits idle

Tags: dask

I'm trying to setup a `dask` distributed cluster, I've installed `dask` on  three machines to get started:

- laptop (where searchCV gets called)
- scheduler (small box where the dask scheduler process lives)
- HPC (Large box expected to do the work)

I have `dask[complete]` installed on the laptop and `dask` on the other machines. 
The worker and scheduler start fine and I can see the dashboards, but I can't send them anything. Running `GridSearchCV` on the laptop get's a result but it comes from  the laptop alone, the worker sits idle.

All machines are windows 7 (HPC is 10) I've checked the ports with `netstat` and it appears that it is really listening where it is supposed to.

When runnign a small example I get the following error:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
scheduler_address = 'tcp://10.X.XX.XX:8786'
client = Client(scheduler_address)

def square(x):
        return x ** 2

def neg(x):
    return -x

A = client.map(square, range(10))
B = client.map(neg, A)
total = client.submit(sum, B)

print(total.result())
```

`INFO - Batched Comm Closed: in <closed TCP>: ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`
`distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback <bound method Client._heartbeat of <Client: scheduler='tcp://10.X.XX.XX:8786' processes=1 cores=10`

I've also filed a [bug](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3862) report as I don't know if this is a bug or ineptitude on my part (I'm guessing later)

Answer (score 0):

Running `client.get_versions(check=True)` revealed all sorts of issues despite a clean install with `-U`. Fixing the environments to be the same fixed that. The laptop can have different versions of stuff installed, at least it worked for the differences I have, YMMV.